# Embeding component into another component

Tags: aem

I have two aem components having different author dialog. Now I want to embed one component onto the other using *htl*. How to do that can anyone help?

I tried using `data-sly-resource` but with that, I cannot author the 2nd component.

Expected to embed both one component into other

Answer (score 0):

Try using HTML tags, depending on the context.

```html
<div data-sly-resource="${'component-ID' @resourceType='path/to/the/component'}" ></div>

OR

<span data-sly-resource="${'component-ID' @resourceType='path/to/the/component'}" ></span>
```